# writing to sqlite failed due to database locked file

Tags: spring-data-jpa

i'm newbie with springboot jpa and get error on writing to sqlite database table,
reading from table is working nomarly.

[SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked. (database is locked)

Here is the detail log:
2022-01-25 13:05:45.295  INFO 2001 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-25 13:05:45.296  INFO 2001 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-25 13:05:45.297  INFO 2001 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
Hibernate: select bike0_.id as id1_0_, bike0_.contact as contact2_0_, bike0_.email as email3_0_, bike0_.model as model4_0_, bike0_.name as name5_0_, bike0_.phone as phone6_0_, bike0_.purchase_date as purchase7_0_, bike0_.purchase_price as purchase8_0_, bike0_.serial_number as serial_n9_0_ from bike bike0_
Hibernate: select bike0_.id as id1_0_0_, bike0_.contact as contact2_0_0_, bike0_.email as email3_0_0_, bike0_.model as model4_0_0_, bike0_.name as name5_0_0_, bike0_.phone as phone6_0_0_, bike0_.purchase_date as purchase7_0_0_, bike0_.purchase_price as purchase8_0_0_, bike0_.serial_number as serial_n9_0_0_ from bike bike0_ where bike0_.id=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
2022-01-25 13:06:00.068  WARN 2001 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 5, SQLState: null
2022-01-25 13:06:00.070 ERROR 2001 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
2022-01-25 13:06:00.120 ERROR 2001 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: error performing isolated work] with root cause

org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1030) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1042) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:1007) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.core.DB.exec(DB.java:178) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.commit(SQLiteConnection.java:421) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.commit(ProxyConnection.java:387) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.commit(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]

Please help me on this.
thank in advanced

Kbg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYxEo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbHd7.png)

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0):

you have to unlock the database file before you can write on it.

Comment: fuser bike.db file show that there is no process handling on it